# Difference between __builtin_addcll and _addcarry_u64

Tags: c++, clang, intel, intrinsics, built-in

Good morning (or good evening),

I was reading some legacy code in my company and I found the following intrinsic was used:

```
_addcarry_u64
```

However, I have to port this code on a platform that does not support it.
After some research, I stumbled upon a Clang builtin that seemed to do the exact same job:

```
__builtin_addcll
```

It has the same arguments (not in the same order but still), however, since there is little to no [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#builtin-functions) about it even on Clang website, I have no clue if they truly are the same or not, especially since return types or argument order is not the same.

I tried to use a macro to remap already used arguments however it did not work (I know it's dirty).

```
#define _addcarry_u64(carryIn, src1, src2, carryOut) __builtin_addcll(src1, src2, carryIn, carryOut)
```

I feel I will have to wrap it in a function for it to work correctly (still I'm not sure it would work)

Can anyone point me to a documentation or to anything that could solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `_addcarry_u64` is the [official intrinsic name from Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=_addcarry_u64) for all Intel platforms
- `__builtin_addcll` is the [intrinsic from Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html) for all platforms supported by Clang
- The `__builtin_uaddll_overflow` family is [the equivalent in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html) for all platforms supported by GCC

The signature for Clang is

```
unsigned long long __builtin_addcll(unsigned long long x,
                                    unsigned long long y,
                                    unsigned long long carryin,
                                    unsigned long long *carryout);
```

and the Intel version is

```
unsigned char _addcarry_u64 (unsigned char c_in,
                             unsigned __int64 a,
                             unsigned __int64 b,
                             unsigned __int64 * out)
```

So your macro is incorrect. `_addcarry_u64` adds 2 number and **returns the carry**, and the sum is returned via a pointer as stated by Intel

> Add unsigned 64-bit integers `a` and `b` with unsigned 8-bit carry-in `c_in` (carry flag), and store the unsigned 64-bit result in `out`, and the carry-out in `dst` (carry or overflow flag).

`__builtin_addcll` OTOH **returns the sum directly** and the carry out is returned via a pointer as you can see right from your [Clang documentation link](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html)

> Clang provides a set of builtins which expose multiprecision arithmetic in a manner amenable to C. They all have the following form:
>
> ```
> unsigned x = ..., y = ..., carryin = ..., carryout;
> unsigned sum = __builtin_addc(x, y, carryin, &carryout);
> ```

So the equivalent to

```
int carryOut = _addcarry_u64(carryIn, x, y, &sum);
```

in Clang is

```
auto sum = __builtin_addcll(x, y, carryIn, &carryOut);
```